# Unable to create the object of the controller in ext js 6.7

Tags: extjs

When migrated from extjs 6.0 to 6.7 i am unable to create the object of the controller

```
init: function(){
    this.Controller = 
Root.app.getController('controller.rootController');
    console.log(this);
},
```

when consoling this it contains null as controller whereas the desired output is that it should contain the object to controller

Comment: It's classic/modern toolkit? in which class is used `init`? Did you required the controller here?

Comment: Why do you have the controller object in the constructor?